# jQuery.css('margin-left') returns incorrect value on mobile Webkit

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ios, mobile-safari

I am using jQuery to get some CSS properties from an element, using `.css('prop')`.

On **iOS**, jQuery returns `0px` when the `margin-left` property is set to `auto`. This doesn't happen anywhere else I tested, and it's not due to device-specific rules being applied.

To be double sure of the latter, I also inspected the code in [WEINRE](http://phonegap.github.com/weinre/), where the inspector shows the correct `auto` values.

## Q:

Any idea why jQuery is returning `0px` instead of `auto`?

---

*Code used to access the CSS property in question (just pre-caching stuff):*

```
this.data.marginRight = this.$el.css('margin-right')
// Firefox returns 'auto'
// Chrome returns 'auto'
// Safari returns 'auto'
// Mobile Safari returns '0px'
```

Comment: Try this `getComputedStyle( this.$el[0] ).getPropertyValue( 'margin-left' )`

Comment: "*anywhere else I tested*" - specify where else you tested. I tested in Firefox (desktop) on Win7, and on an element which has `margin: 0 auto;`, I too get `'0px'` for `margin-left`...

Comment: jQuery will always return a *N* value with 'px', and `auto` is not such case. Anyway, to return that *N* you have to strictly define in your CSS that value. ( @Šime CRO power! :D )

Comment: @Šime Vidas: I tested on Chrome, Firefox, Safari & Mobile Safari on a Mac. All latest releases.

Comment: @Šime Vidas: `getComputedStyle( this.$el[0] ).getPropertyValue( 'margin-left' )` works as you advertise, and I assume it's faster than using `jQuery.css()`. However it still returns a `0px` string.

Comment: @tmslnz I made [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5JvAq/). I get `'0px'` in Firefox, Opera, and Safari, and I get about `'160px'` in Chrome, and IE. So, even though the margin-left is set to `'auto'`, I don't get that value in any of my browsers. You will have to make a demo...

Comment: it probably returns the computed value instead of the string you defined.

Comment: it normally does, as the fiddle shows too. However I swear jQuery was returning the non-computed value. I still have no clue why that was happening tho'.